# How can I send information from one html page to another?

Tags: html

I want to create an html page which contains a text box.   When I am given input and the Enter key is pressed, I want it to go to another html page and display the typed keyword.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a server-side scripting language to facilitate the manipulation of the inputted data on the form, so that it gets "saved" and displayed in the other html page. I suggest you try reading about PHP, and then turn to handling information in Web Forms...just a thought!

Comment: really, in different html pages? i didn't know that, could you provide a link please?

Comment: i want only basic html to html -- it is my interview question

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript for that. Check this Tutorial : [How do I pass variables between two pages? (GET method)](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5442)

Comment: Also, depending on version of browser: HTML 5 provides a localStore & sessionStore mechanism along side a SQL database ( hit or miss on support ), and lastly a messaging mechanism.